# Fechar app ao finalizar fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-fragment

Olá, tenho uma aplicação, se resume em: uma `Activity` e um `fragment`. A `activity` chama o `fragment` através do `onCreate`:

Código da `Activivity` que chama o `fragment`:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensagem);

            chamaSecondActivity();
        }

        public void chamaSecondActivity() {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerMensagem, new SecondActivity());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
```

Gostaria que quando voltasse do fragment o app fechasse e não retornasse para a activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode remover essa linha do seu codigo:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Ela faz o botão voltar, voltar do fragment e não da Activity.